# 'yield all' in Saga is not waiting for all the effects to complete

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a Saga like so (some pseudocodish).

Saga1 calls an API. Based on the result, I need to call two further APIs. If all the APIs succeed, I call onSuccess, else onFailure.

The code seems to almost work fine, but not quite. The problem I facing with `yield all` is that it considered saga2 and saga3 complete as soon as the first yield put was called (see comment in saga2/3). It didn't wait for the fetch yield to finish.

I think it's partly due to my misunderstanding of what a "complete effect" means. But apart from that, I want yield all to wait until everything is done. I want any exceptions thrown by fetch in saga2/3 to be caught by catch in saga1.

```
saga1(action) {

    const { onSuccess, onFailure } = action.payload;

    try {
        yield fetch...

        if(response.some_condition) yield all([
            put(saga2()),
            put(saga3())
        ])

        onSuccess();

    }
    catch(e) {
        onFailure();
    }
}

saga2(action) {

    yield put(someaction()) // This yields
    yield fetch...
}

saga3(action) {

    yield put(someaction()) // This yield
    yield fetch...
}
```

This code below is related to my comment below about catch not working

```
action1 () { // action2 is same
    try {
        yield fetch();
        yield put(FINISHED_1);
    }
    catch(e) {
        throw (e);
    }
}

saga1() {
    try {
        yield put(action1());
        yield put(action2());

        yield all([
            take(FINISHED_1),
            take(FINISHED_2),
        ])
        console.log("this doesn't print if exception in either action");
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log("this doesn't print if exception in either action");
    }
    finally {
        console.log("this prints fine");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example code seems a bit off. You are passing a saga to `put` which is incorrect. You can pass an action to `put`, like `put({ type: 'ACTION_2' })`, and then `saga2` listens for that action via `takeEvery('ACTION_2', saga2)`. Or you can pass a saga to a `call`, like `call(saga2, arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: @bsapaka I just simplified the code for simplicity. I am actually calling put({type:ACTION2}) put({type:ACTION3}), which in turn calls saga2 or 3.

Comment: you can use `yield take(ACTION_3_FINISHED)` to wait until `ACTION_3_FINISHED` is dispatched

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) To wait for multiple `call` effects to run to completion:

```
yield all([
    call(saga2, arg1, arg2, ...),
    call(saga3, arg1, arg2, ...)
]);
```

2) To dispatch multiple actions and wait for their success actions to be dispatched:

```
yield put(action1());
yield put(action2());

yield all([
    take(ACTION_1_SUCCESS),
    take(ACTION_2_SUCCESS)
]);
```

**Edits responding to comments**

If you call the sagas directly with `all` (#1 above), then you can catch errors conventionally

```
try {
    yield all([
        call(saga2, arg1, arg2, ...),
        call(saga3, arg1, arg2, ...)
    ]);
} catch (e) {
    // ...
}
```

But if a saga `put`s actions that other sagas listen on, that saga does not receive those exceptions. `Saga1` is not a parent of or attached to those sagas. It just dispatches actions, and some other tasks elsewhere listen and respond.

For `Saga1` to be aware of errors in those sagas, the sagas should not throw errors, but instead dispatch an action with an error payload:

```
function* saga2(action) {
    try {
        const result = yield call(...);
        yield put(action2Success(result));
    } catch (e) {
        yield put(action2Failure(e.message));
    }
}
```

A saga that triggers `saga2` (via `put(action2())`) can handle success and failure:

```
function* saga1(action) {
    yield put(action2());
    yield put(action3());

    const [success, failure] = yield race([
        // if this occurs first, the race will exit, and success will be truthy
        all([
            take(ACTION_2_SUCCESS),
            take(ACTION_3_SUCCESS)
        ]),

        // if either of these occurs first, the race will exit, and failure will be truthy
        take(ACTION_2_FAILURE),
        take(ACTION_3_FAILURE)
    ]);

    if (failure) {
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Sagas should handle exceptions and update the store with an error state, not throw errors. Throwing errors in sagas gets messy when working with saga concurrency constructs. For example, you cannot directly catch an error thrown by a `fork`ed task. Also, using actions to signal saga results keeps a good event log in your store, on which other sagas/reducers can respond to. When you `call` other sagas, the action that is supposed to initiate that saga (e.g. `takeEvery(THE_ACTION, ...)`) doesn't get dispatched.

Comment: Oh man, this is ideal. Exactly what I was asking for. This isn't solving one problem for me (which is what I initially wanted to do, but never asked since I thought this will fix it). In action 1's saga, I make an API call, and in catch I re-throw the error. Since yield all is supposed to throw those errors to me, a try/catch around yield all should catch the error thrown. But it's not. But it also doesn't compute the code after yield all, which means it's certainly seeing an error which is why it's bailing out. But it's not caught in catch. My finally still runs. More in original comment

Comment: BTW, I am still selecting your comment as accepted answer since this fully answered my initial question. I just thought the catch thingy would work, but guess not. If you could look into my edits in the original comment, that'd be amazing!

Comment: Can you check https://jsbin.com/huwobicege/edit?js This explains why I am using catch. All non-200 responses get caught. It works fine and dandy, but not if I call one saga from another saga. I guess I can refactor it in a way to not use catch, but that kind of seems the best way to do it for single API calls. I am just baffled who an error is thrown, which forces the calling try block to stop midway (hence it sees the error, and doesn't execute the rest of the try block), call the finally part, but not catch.

Comment: I just re-read your response. Let me try it out. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: I added a few things for clarification

Comment: @brietsparks I am following the first case "To wait for multiple call effects to run to completion" using    ```yield all([
    call(saga2, arg1, arg2, ...),
    call(saga3, arg1, arg2, ...)
]);```  I need to call the same function let's say saga2 with different arguments each time for 30 times. how should I do that without writing the call(saga2, {arg1}) 30 times?